# Prestashop admin module tpl issue

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm working on a `prestashop` custom module development, my idea is to create a custom export module, I'm able to install the module and add the menu under catalog menu. the only issue is while installing the `tpl` files not copying to the admin template folder ? 
Should we copy these view with copy method inside install section of module ?

in my controller I'm trying to load the tpl file from

```
public function initContent() {
        parent::initContent();
        $smarty = $this->context->smarty;
        $smarty->assign('test', 'test1');
        $this->setTemplate('wwmexport/wwmexport.tpl');


    }
```

This path file is not exist after module installation `$this->setTemplate('wwmexport/wwmexport.tpl');`  when I create it manually everything works fine.

I need to know is there any option to load the tpl from my module path something like below.

```
return $this->display(_PS_MODULE_DIR_ . 'wwmexport/views/templates/admin/wwmexport.tpl');
```

but that not working :(

My module structure is as follows.

```
wwmexport
  controllers
    admin
     Adminwwmcontroller.php
  views
    templates
      admin
          wwmexport.tpl

  wwmexport.php
```

controller file have

```
class AdminWwmExportController extends AdminController {

    protected $module;

    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();

    }

    public function display() {

        parent::display();

    }


    public function initContent() {

        if (Tools::getValue('method') != "") {
            $method = Tools::getValue('method');
            $this->$method();
        }

        parent::initContent();
        /*$smarty = $this->context->smarty;
        $smarty->assign(array('test', 'test1'));*/
        //$this->setTemplate('wwmexport.tpl');
        global $smarty;
        $smarty->display(_PS_MODULE_DIR_ . 'wwmexport/views/templates/admin/wwmexport.tpl');

    }
}
```

my module file wwmexport.php as follows.

```
class WwmExport extends Module {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->name = 'wwmexport';
        $this->tab = 'export';
        $this->version = '1.0.0';
        $this->author = 'Jobin Jose';
        $this->need_instance = 0;
        $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.6', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_);
        $this->bootstrap = true;

        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->l('Export');
        $this->description = $this->l('Custom Export Features for Products');
        $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Are you sure you would like to uninstall?');
    }

    public function install($delete_params = true) {

        if (!parent::install()
            /*|| !copy(_PS_MODULE_DIR_ . 'wwmexport/views/templates/admin/wwmexport.tpl', _PS_ADMIN_DIR_ . '/themes/default/template/wwmexport.tpl')*/
            || !$this->installModuleTab('AdminWwmExport', array(1 => 'Product Export'), 9)
        ) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function uninstall() {
        if (!parent::uninstall()
            || !$this->uninstallModuleTab('AdminWwmExport')) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private function installModuleTab($tabClass, $tabName, $idTabParent) {
        $tab = new Tab();

        $tab->name = $tabName;

        $tab->class_name = $tabClass;

        $tab->module = $this->name;

        $tab->id_parent = $idTabParent;

        if (!$tab->save()) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }

    private function uninstallModuleTab($tabClass) {
        $idTab = Tab::getIdFromClassName($tabClass);

        if ($idTab != 0) {

            $tab = new Tab($idTab);

            $tab->delete();

            return true;

        }

        return false;

    }

}
```

**Solved**

rewrite the `initContent()`  as follows.

```
public function initContent() {    

        parent::initContent();
        $smarty = $this->context->smarty;
        $content = $smarty->fetch(_PS_MODULE_DIR_ . 'wwmexport/views/templates/admin/wwmexport.tpl');
        $this->context->smarty->assign(array('content' => $this->content . $content));

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so it works for me

```
$this->display(__FILE__ , 'views/templates/admin/wwmexport.tpl');
```

Comment: thanks for your anwser , but it didn't work for me. when I put you code sample it shows blank content area , also the left side admin menus shows twice ? any idea ?

Comment: Where is your code? in main file of module or in AdminController? you can post the structure of your module?

Comment: I just noticed it showing in the page source before html tag when I use below code `global $smarty;
  $smarty->display(_PS_MODULE_DIR_ . 'wwmexport/views/templates/admin/wwmexport.tpl');`

Comment: I just updated the code, can you figure out any thing wrong

Comment: i am not sure but I would try:
    $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
        'content' => $this->content . "Your code html in tpl",
    ))

Comment: not working , I found similar question on forum too https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/436680-load-tpl-from-custom-backoffice-menu/ no answers :(. by the way thanks for your time.